# What is wrong with this C code to encode/decode messages

Tags: c

Our code is supposed to have two files. code.c that encodes and decode.c that decodes from stdin. It shouldn't have an issue with any length file sizes, assuming that each line is 120 characters or less.

My encode code...

```
void encode(char pass[]) {
    char buffer[121], encoded[121];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, 120, stdin)) {
        for (i = 0; i < (strlen(buffer)); i++) {
            if (j > (strlen(pass) - 1))
                j = 0;

            encoded[i] = buffer[i] + pass[j];
            j++;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, encoded);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, buffer);
}
```

And the exact opposite, the decode code:

```
void decode(char pass[]) {
    char buffer[121], decoded[121];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, 120, stdin)) {
        for (i = 0; i < (strlen(buffer)); i++) {
            if (j > (strlen(pass) - 1))
                j = 0;

            decoded[i] = buffer[i] - pass[j];
            j++;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, decoded);
    }
}
```

The code seems to execute and work almost as intended, except that it seems to encode more data on the last line when I do CTRL+D to terminate. So when I go to decode, it decodes properly except for the last line.

Edit:

here is some sample input

```
code password > crypt
This is a test
file that will contain
encrypted information
```

That should put

```
This is a test
file that will contain
encrypted information
```

into a file named crypt with the password of 'password'

The file crypt looks like this:

```
ÄÉÜæ<97>Øå<84>Ñ<81>çØêãÊÙÍØ<93>ë×ÓØ<90>ØÜßã<8f>ÕÓÞÕÔÜåy×ÒÓÓìãëÔÖ<84>ÙÏÙâéÜÓØÙÐá}y
```

Decryption output looks like this however:

```
decode password < crypt
This is a test
file that will contain
encrypted information
??
```

The ?? is garbage text that it's pulling out of the file. Not sure why its either encoding or decoding more than was input into stdin..

Another round of input/output does this:

```
./code password > crypt
testing this
file to encrypt
stuff
./decode password < crypt
testing this
file to encrypt
!J
```

Whereas it's much more clear that there are issues happening with my last line.

Comment: Can you add to your question an example of the actual output and the expected output for some example input?

Comment: I added some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you do not put a null terminator at the end of `encoded` or `decoded` before passing it to `fprintf()`.

Note however that you should not pass `decoded` as a format string to `fprintf`, it would invoke undefined behavior if it were to contain `%` characters.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encode(const char pass[]) {
    int c, i = 0, len = strlen(pass);

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c + pass[i++]);
        if (i >= len)
            i = 0;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

void decode(const char pass[]) {
    int c, i = 0, len = strlen(pass);

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c - pass[i++]);
        if (i >= len)
            i = 0;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

If you want to keep reading input one line at a line, here is a simplified version of your code that does not copy the string to a different buffer and therefore does not need to store the null terminator:

```
void encode(char pass[]) {
    char buffer[121];
    int i = 0, j = 0, len = strlen(pass);

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            buffer[i] += pass[j++];
            if (j >= len)
                j = 0;
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

Note however that this method fails if the input file contains null bytes or characters such that adding a byte from the password produces the value `0`. It is impossible if both the file and the password contains only ASCII bytes, but if you try and encode a binary file or a foreign text file, you may run into this issue.  The simpler version with `getchar()` does not have this problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I add a null terminated at the end before passing to fprintf if I were to continue using my code?

Comment: @MaxLo: you would add a statement `encoded[i] = '\0';` before the `fprintf()` in `encode()` and `decoded[i] = '\0';` before the `fprintf()` in `decode()`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your encoded string as format string to `fprintf`. If the encoded string contains `%` character, it will  make `fprintf` to interpret it as a beginning of format specifier with obvious catastrophic consequences. Don't pass arbitrary strings as format strings to `fprintf`. If you want to `fprintf` an arbitrary string, do

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s", encoded);
```

This applies to both of your functions, since the original text might easily contain a `%` character as well.

Also, as @chqrlie noted already, you never zero-terminate your recipient buffers (i.e. `encoded` and `decoded`) in either function.

Comment: Thank you for that. Helped the warning I was getting, but still getting the weird error of garbage...